Name of a point useful in triangle constructions with squares erected on sides
Does the point $S$ or its associated circle in the diagram below have a name? I stumbled upon it today examining some variations on Euclid's construct for proving the Pythagorean theorem. The triangle $ABC$ is arbitrary, not right, the pairs of dashed lines (e.g., $CC_2, AA_1$) are perpendicular and of equal length (e.g., quarter-turn on $B$), and their intersection $M_B$ lies on a circle with center $S$ defined by two such intersections and the opposite vertex, e.g., $M_B,M_C, A$. Some features of the circle surprised me - e.g., $RST \parallel BC$ - and it contains enough points of concurrence I thought it might actually be (obscurely) named.


FYI: Barycentric coordinates of $S$ are
$$a \sin A + b \cos B + c \cos C;:;
b \cos C,(\cos A + \sin A);:;
c \cos B,(\cos A + \sin A)$$
